# Axios get on a property change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have list of months and I want to retrieve from the API the appointments for each of those months on click. What I have now:

HTML

```
<div class="months">
    <a v-on:click="retrieveCalendar(index + 1, currentYear, month)" v-bind:class="{active : month.isActive}" v-for='(month, index) in months'>{{ month.name }}</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
methods: {
    retrieveCalendar: function(month, year, object = []) {
        axios.get('api/calendar/' + year + '/' + month + '/1').then(response => (this.days = response.data));
    }
}
```

This works, but is abysmal. I need lots of other stuff to happen in that method, like for example - change the `isActive` parameter.

I am also calling this method in `create()` in order to call the initial set of events - is that the right approach?

Is there a way to use computed properties to watch `year` and `month` and if they are changed to fire the `retrieveCalendar` method? Or should I be using `method` at all or should I move this somehow to a computed property? Or is there another hundreth way for this to be done properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution:

### Simplicity

By simply saving the index on click, you make all the required data available without passing arguments to the `retrieveCalendar` method.

### `isActive`

As you can see below, this also makes it so we don't even need an `isActive` property. In the class binding, you can simply compare the active index against the current index.

### Firing `retrieveCalendar` when `year` and `month` Change

This is what [Vue watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) are for. Since you're calling the same method multiple times, and you already have the method, it's most efficient to register the watcher as a string of the method name.

### Initialization via `$vm#create()`

Is this correct? Yes. Is there a better way? Yes.

By passing an object with the property `immediate: true` to a Vue watcher, you can skip the `#create()` call. Vue will call it on the create hook for you.
The catch is that this is an undocumented Vue API and it might confuse someone else reading your code.

Several of the above tricks were learned here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YZ5DwlLSt8

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: _ => ({
    activeMonthIndex: new Date().getMonth(),
    currentYear: new Date().getYear(),
    months: [
      "January", 
      "February", 
      "March", 
      "April", 
      "May", 
      "June", 
      "July", 
      "August", 
      "September", 
      "October", 
      "November", 
      "December"
    ]
  }),
  
  methods: {
  
    retrieveCalendar () {
      let month = this.activeMonthIndex + 1;
      let year = this.currentYear;
      let object = this.months[this.activeMonthIndex];
      
      return console.log(
        `I don't actually have access to your API...`
      );
      
      axios.get(
        'api/calendar/' +
        year +
        '/' +
        month +
        '/1'
      ).then(response => {
        this.days = response.data
      });
    }
    
  },
  
  watch: {
  
    activeMonthIndex: {
      handler: 'retrieveCalendar',
      /* 
        `immediate: true` ensures that this method 
        will run on create, as well as when the watched 
        property changes.
      */
      immediate: true
    },
    
    currentYear: 'retrieveCalendar'
    
  }
  
});
```

```css
body{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#42e695 0,#3bb2b8 100%);font-family:futura,helvetica;background-repeat:no-repeat;height:100vh;width:100%;padding:2px}a{transition:all 500ms ease-out;display:inline-flex; margin: 5px;background:#FAFAFA;padding:20px;border-radius:5px;box-shadow:0 20px 50px -10px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}h1{color:#fff;text-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}a:hover{transform:translateY(-2px);cursor:pointer;}a.active{filter:invert(100%)}.months{display:flex;flex-direction: column wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:flex-start;align-items: flex-end;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <p v-if="activeMonthIndex != -1">
    Loading Calendar for {{ months[activeMonthIndex] }}...
    (not really it's just a demo)
  </p>
 
  <div class="months">

    <a 
      v-for='(month, index) in months' 
      @click="activeMonthIndex = index"
      :class="{active : index == activeMonthIndex }"
      >
      {{ month }}
    </a>

  </div>

</div>
```